# Configure EasyTracker programmatically

Tags: android, easytracker

I am using EasyTracker in my app.
I need to change the `ga_trackingId` programmatically and can't use the xml.
I couldn't find any thing about it anywhere..
Is it posible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple tracker each with a different ga_trackingId as stated in the documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v2/advanced#multiple-trackers

Instead of "changing" ga_trackingId, you should put some condition to use one tracker or another based on your needs.